How to direct a file to an alternate subfolder if specified subfolder does not exist
I have a situation whereby when btn_Finished is clicked it should export Statement_file to one of the existing subfolders with USERS names fld_Abi, fld_Clint, fld_Dell, fld_Many, fld_More and fld_TEMPFolder(not assigned to any user). All the subfolders resides in a folder named FLD_ReportPickup and are all named after each user except the fld_TEMPFolder which is to be used only when a username is not setup or does not exist in the folder FLD_ReportPickup.
This is what I have tried:
Dim User As String
Dim TempDAPath   
Dim DAPath

If USER = "" Or IsNull(User) Then
    USER = "fld_TEMPFolder"

    DAPath = "W:\Service Center\Reports\Dealerships\DealershipsONLY\PROCESSORS" 
'(Statement_file is correctly autosaved here in the "PROCESSORS" subfolder)

    TempDAPath ="W:\ServiceCenter\Reports\Dealerships\DealershipsONLY\PROCESSORS\FLD_ReportPickup" & USER & "
'(Statement_file is NEITHER saving in any user's subfolder NOR in the designated "fld_TempFolder")

End If

I need the btn_Finished to save Statement_File to respective USER's subfolder, and in the case of a new user that has not been set up, and/or a subfolder that does not exist saved in fld_TEMPFolder.

Make an array of known user-names and check the USER with this array items.
FUNCTION GetPathByUser(USER AS VARIANT) AS STRING
    CONST Base_Folder = "W:\Service Center\Reports\Dealerships\DealershipsONLY\PROCESSORS\"
    CONST Unkown_USER_Folder = "fld_TEMPFolder"
    DIM Known_Users
    Known_Users = ARRAY("fld_Abi" , "fld_Clint" , "fld_Dell" , "fld_Many" , "fld_More")
    DIM User_Folder AS STRING
    User_Folder = Unkown_USER_Folder
    DIM i AS INTEGER
    FOR i = LBOUND(Known_Users) TO UBOUND(Known_Users)
        IF USER = Known_Users(i) THEN
            User_Folder = USER
        END IF
    NEXT i
    GetPathByUser = Base_Folder + User_Folder
END FUNCTION

